# Find the closest number to our number

Tags: python, numbers

First, I randomly choose a number
And then, using input from others, I ask them for the numbers
And finally, the closest number to my number should be displayed
How do I write this code?

who  can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randint(1,10)
players = 5
userGuesses = []

for i in range(players):
    userGuesses.append(int(input("Enter your guess here: ")))

closestNumber = userGuesses[0]

for number in userGuesses:
    difference = abs(number-randomNumber)
    if abs(closestNumber-randomNumber) > difference:
        closestNumber = number

print(closestNumber)
```

This should work - you can change the 'players' variable to the number of users that are competing.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is in the form of a game in the terminal, where you write your answers:

```
from random import randint

number_of_players = int(input('Enter number of players: '))
minimum = int(input('Enter minimum number: '))
maximum = int(input('Enter maximum number: '))
answer = randint(minimum, maximum)  # draw a secret random number

answers = {}
for player in range(1, number_of_players + 1):  # collect answers from players
    answers[str(player)] = int(input(f'Player {player} answer: '))

winner, value = min(answers.items(), key=lambda x: abs(answer - x[1]))  # search closest answer
print(f'Answer is {answer}. Winner is player {winner} with {value}.')
```